# Diagnosing why the left side of a print detaches from the board

Tags: creality-ender-3, heated-bed, bed-leveling, adhesion

I have and Ender 3 Pro, which I'm enjoying except for an intractable problem. No matter how carefully I level the nozzle and tighten the X belt, using this [great guide](https://all3dp.com/2/ender-3-bed-leveling-all-you-need-to-know/), the prints seem to be tilting to the right, particularly if they're tall. I realize this is a common problem, but I'm at a loss for what it's called and where the problem is most likely to be.

The first sign of trouble in paradise is that, after two layers of a simple rectangular base for a [Galton Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine) I'm trying to build that uses sand, the right side is clearly thinner than the left:

[image]

This is with a translucent Overture PETG filament, 1.75 mm.

For the board itself, which is about 15 cm tall and looks MUCH better if printed vertically, I notice after about 3-4 cm that the bottom of the left side is becoming detached from the bed:

[image]

This gets progressively worse as the print goes on:

[image]

The entire Galton Box takes six hours to print using the default PETG settings in Cura for a default level of detail, so I'd really prefer to find a way to diagnose the problem sooner. I know this is not a new problem, but I'd be grateful for any guidance on what it's called or links to how to fix it -- and how to determine if it's a hardware problem or not.

Also, out of curiosity: If the machine isn't PERFECTLY level on the table -- my work desk appears to slant by about 2° -- could that be implicated?

Comment: The [level of the table top](/a/7892) has **nothing** to do with the levelling of the printer, nor with the leaning of your prints! You're just having adhesion problems, use a specific print adhesion spray or a hairspray or glue sticks.

Comment: Thanks! Would that explain the uneven level in the first photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uneven level is explained by the unfortunate choice of the printer manufacturer to **not have** a second Z lead screw. It is pretty difficult to level these printers, it is all a combination of the correct X belt tension and roller tension. The uneven level in the first picture is what is causing your print to detach, As can be seen you've got a lot of "squish" on the right side, but less adhesion (seen by the less transparent color) on the left, therefore it would fail on the left.

You need to:

- level better,
- fix the skew XZ gantry or
- use an [adhesive](/a/11183) (and/or a `brim`).

---

Please note that the [level of the table top](/a/7892) has **nothing** to do with the leveling of the printer, nor with the leaning of your prints. You're just having adhesion problems as a result of an uneven bed/gantry.

Comment: Thank you! A combination of meticulous leveling, brimming -- actually, skirting, just to be safe -- and a gantry adjustment has improved this a lot. This YouTube video was a savior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36u4gberzC8

Comment: On curious thing I noticed was that, when a fully tightened (lowered) each corner as a starting point, as the video suggests, the back left corner was about 4 mm higher. I noticed there's a piece connected to the adjustment rotator on this corner below the bed connecting a cable, but it's only being held in place and limits the freedom of the adjustment.